# React Select Async cleaning the results from dropdown

Tags: react-select

The problem I'm having is that the react select is clearing the results in the dropdown after search.

I'm looking for a way to keep the results listed in dropdown, as I list in the first example in the sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/7yp7zr9r9x

Partial code:

```
    export default class App extends Component {
    searchTitles = movieTitle => {
      if (!movieTitle) return
      const urlRequest = `${SEARCH_URL}{movieTitle}`
      const newRequest = axios.get(urlRequest)

      if (newRequest) {
        // new promise: pending
        return newRequest.then(response => {
        // promise resolved : now I have the data
        const compare = response.data.results.filter(i =>
          i.overview.toLowerCase().includes(movieTitle.toLowerCase())
        )
        return compare.map(film => ({
          label: film.title
        }))
      })
    }
  }

   render() {
      <AsyncSelect
        cacheOptions
        defaultOptions
        loadOptions={this.searchTitles}
       />
   }
}
```

Here is the sandbox for the problem:
https://codesandbox.io/s/7yp7zr9r9x

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the prop defaultOptions to true in your Async setup, which tells the Async component to get the default options from loadOptions prop. If the prop returns values (or a promise which should resolve in values) the component binds them onto the defaultOptions state to render as default options.

From the docs:

The default set of options to show before the user starts searching. When set to true, the results for loadOptions('') will be autoloaded.

The request you make in your loadOptions function is returning an error on first render. So there can not be any values to set as default options.

---

So basically it is needed to have some "default" search as the loadOptions function will be invoked by the first time due to the defaultOptions set to true.

Fixed example:
https://codesandbox.io/s/7yp7zr9r9x